# How to list the package repository URL in SUSE?

Tags: linux, package, repository, opensuse, suse

I tried `zypper repos` but it does not list the URL of the repository. I need this URL as I need the same package repository in another machine and this package repository is private to our organization. Is there a way I can get the URL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose you can use

```
zypper repos -u
```

or

```
zypper lr -u
```

which will also give you the URI for the repository.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to the previous answer:

```
zypper lr -u | grep <target repository>
```

It would display only the output for the repository that you are looking for.